# $x^{311} \equiv 662 \mod{713}$

Tags: number-theory

We have to find $x$ such that $x^{311} \equiv 662 \mod{713}$

The example given in my notes has a few typos and the professor is unavailable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$713=23 \cdot 31 $$

By Chinese Remainder Theorem, you need to solve
$$x^{311} \equiv 662 \pmod{23} \\
x^{311} \equiv 662 \pmod{31}$$
or equivalently

$$x^{311} \equiv 18 \pmod{23} \\
x^{311} \equiv 11 \pmod{31}$$

It follows that $x$ is invertible in both arithmetics, and then by Fermat Little Theorem we have
$$x^3\equiv 18 \pmod{23} \Rightarrow x^{-1} \equiv x^{21} \equiv 18^7 \pmod{23}\Rightarrow x \equiv (18^7)^{-1} \pmod{23}$$
and
$$x^{11} \equiv 11 \pmod{31} \Rightarrow x^{3} \equiv x^{33} \equiv 11^{3} \pmod{31}\,.$$

Now use the CRT to find $x \pmod{713}$.

**Second solution**

As 662 is invertible, it follows that $x$ is invertible and hence, by Euler Theorem we have

$$x^{660} \equiv 1 \pmod {713} \,.$$

now, find $a,b$ so that

$$a\cdot 311 +b \cdot 660=1$$

Then

$$x= x^{1}=x^{a\cdot 311 +b \cdot 660}=(x^{311})^a\cdot(x^{660})^b=662^a \pmod{713} \,.$$

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain? :)

Comment: Who's the down voter?

Comment: Im not familiar with the chinese remainder theorem and we never talked about that in class.

Comment: @observeRReacts Did you do the Euler Theorem?

Comment: Yes and fermat's little theorem

Comment: @observeRReacts I added a second solution which only uses Euler and a simple Diophantine equation.

Comment: That looks more familiar...but that is the answer? How would I now get a answer for x? Or did you already do that and I don't see how?

Comment: @observeRReacts Well, you need to calculate $a$. I assume you covered the Extended Euclidian Algorithm (a.k.a. Bezoutian algorithm)... If not, note that $a$ is the inverse of $311$ in $\pmod{660}$ arithmetic...

Comment: I'm not familiar with the extended euclidian algorithm

Comment: @Miller.Steve Do you know how to calculate the inverse of $311$ modulo $660$?

Comment: No, no idea. How do you do that?

Comment: @Miller.Steve Check the (extended) Euclidian Algorithm a.k.a. the Bezoutian algorithm.... It really would surprise me if you learned FLT and Euler Theorem but not how to calculate inverses...

Comment: Yes, we did.  I didn't understand it. Where did your 660 come from?

Comment: @Miller.Steve What is $\phi(713)$?

Comment: 713 = 23*31 phi713 = 22*30 = 660